# I want use sumif function and show the data for each channel per month

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have data on 1st image which i want it to be visible by each channel monthly on 2nd image attached by using sumifs
[Raw data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/slBKF.jpg)
[Main sheet to use formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWWVg.jpg)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want the data to to visible in the 2nd image attached where in 1st image it show retail january 500 february 900 i want these numbers in 2nd image by using sumifs

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the following formula, instead of using `SUMIFS()` use `SUMPRODUCT()`, because to make `SUMIFS()` work one would need an additional function, since will work with ranges when each ranges have same number of rows and columns. The second method shows on how to use `SUMIFS()` with `INDEX()`+`MATCH()` function. The formulas shown below should work.

[image]

---

Using `SUMPRODUCT()` and `LOOKUP()` function for one of the **`criteria`**

• Formula used in cell <kbd>H3</kbd>

```
=SUMPRODUCT(
    (H$2 = $C$2:$E$2) *
        ($G3 = $A$3:$A$14) *
        (
            LOOKUP(
                2,
                1 /
                    (
                        $H$1:H$1 <>
                            ""
                    ),
                $H$1:H$1
            ) = $B$3:$B$14
        ) * $C$3:$E$14
)
```

---

Or, Using `SUMIFS()` with `INDEX()`+`MATCH()` functions for the `sum_range`

• Formula used in cell <kbd>H3</kbd>

```
=SUMIFS(
    INDEX(
        $C$3:$E$14,
        ,
        MATCH(
            H$2,
            $C$2:$E$2,
            0
        )
    ),
    $A$3:$A$14, $G3,
    $B$3:$B$14, LOOKUP(
        2,
        1 / ($H$1:H$1 <> ""),
        $H$1:H$1
    )
)
```

---

Change the cell references and ranges accordingly as per your suit. Both the formula shown above needs to fill down and fill right.

---

And if you are using `MS365` then try using `MAKEARRAY()` function to spill the output using one single dynamic array formula:

```
=LET(
     _Months, G3:G14,
     _Header1, H2:S2,
     _Header2, SCAN(,H1:S1,LAMBDA(x,y,IF(y="",x,y))),
     _Rows, ROWS(_Months),
     _Columns, COLUMNS(_Header1),
     MAKEARRAY(_Rows,_Columns,LAMBDA(r,c,
     SUMIFS(INDEX(C3:E14,,XMATCH(INDEX(_Header1,c),C2:E2)),A3:A14,
            INDEX(_Months,r),B3:B14,INDEX(_Header2,,c)))))
```

---

Comment: Thank you for helping with sumproduct formula. I want to understand how it work the * sign  and lookup(2,1

Comment: @Fahad `*` acts as `AND()` logic, while `LOOKUP()` is used to find the last non-empty cell in the range. Also if that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers)